# error when trying to import tensorflow GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

here's the code that i use to check if tf.gpu is working or not

```
import tensorflow as tf 
if tf.test.gpu_device_name(): 
    print('Default GPU Device:{}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
   print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

and here's the error

```
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
2020-11-22 21:53:40.971514: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-11-22 21:53:40.971756: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the GPU with Tensorflow, you must install the gpu version of Tensorflow

`python -m pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Make sure that you are also using a 64 bit version of python, as it will only work with those parameters.

**EDIT:**

As of Tensorflow 2.0+, both the CPU and GPU versions of Tensorflow have been packaged together.

To get Tensorflow to work with your GPU, you need to download [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuDNN). Depending on what CUDA version you have, you will need to place some header files and some dll files in the file location of where you installed CUDA.

Comment: If you are using tensorflow 2.0 or higher you just need to install tensorflow. It automaically installs both the CPU and GPU modules.

Comment: @GerryP My apologizes, I forgot that Tensorflow packaged them now. I’ll edit my answer accordingly.